# Large Spreadsheet Comparison For Loop. Is there a faster way?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using a For loop to iterate through a 10k row spreadsheet and compare the data with another spreadsheet of similar size. As you may have guessed this takes a considerable amount of time. Is there a faster method?

I have tried using a For loop starting from the top of one sheet and then comparing each row's information with the second sheet using the Find method. I cannot use the AutoFilter Method to shorten up the search range in any way.

```
Private Sub Import_NewReport()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Order Entry 
Summary - Detail Report.csv")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Master")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Order Entry Summary - Detail Re")
ws1LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ws2LastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ws2.AutoFilterMode = False
i = 1  

For ws2Row = 2 To ws2LastRow

JN = ws2.Cells(ws2Row, "D").Text ' Job Number from New Report

If ws1.Range("D:D").Find(JN) Is Nothing Then

ws1.Cells(ws1LastRow + i, "A").EntireRow.Value = ws2.Cells(ws2Row, "A").EntireRow.Value
ws1.Cells(ws1.Range("D:D").Find(JN).Row, "BB").Value = GetGUID

i = i + 1

Else

rTo = ws1.Range("D:D").Find(JN).Row
ws2.Cells(ws2Row, "A").Resize(, 10).Value = ws1.Cells(rTo, "A").Resize(, 10).Value
ws2.Cells(ws2Row, "M").Resize(, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(rTo, "M").Resize(, 2).Value
ws2.Cells(ws2Row, "Z").Value = ws1.Cells(rTo, "Z").Value
ws2.Cells(ws2Row, "AH").Value = ws1.Cells(rTo, "AH").Value
ws2.Cells(ws2Row, "AB").Value = ws1.Cells(rTo, "AB").Value
ws2.Cells(ws2Row, "AX").Value = ws1.Cells(rTo, "AX").Value

If ws1.Cells(rTo, "BB").Value = "" Then
ws1.Cells(rTo, "BB").Value = GetGUID
End If
End If
Next ws2Row
End Sub
```

Comment: load both sheets data into variant arrays and loop those.

Comment: Maybe use Microsoft's Inquire add-in instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Or even better, use an actual database that manages your primary keys for you.

Comment: A dictionary is another possibility. In one pass through `ws1` build up a dictionary keyed by the job numbers. Then iterate over `ws2`, looking up the keys instantly. Your use of `Find` makes your approach quadratic under the hood. Two independent passes will keep it linear.

Comment: Would it be just as good to use the built in Collection object?

Comment: I'm going to have to do some research. I am VERY wet behind the ears in VBA. Programming in general for that matter. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @Raudert the built-in collection object isn't quite as useful when as a dictionary is when used as a hash table. Furthermore, it [seems to be slower](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/comparing-two-lists-vba-udf-shootout-between-linear-search-binary-search-collection-and-dictionary/) for your problem size.